# Deserialize string considering empty list as empty string

Tags: gson, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to receive results from an API following theses scheme :

- `{ "somekey": "somestringvalue" }`
- `{ "somekey": [] }`
- `{ "somekey": "" }`

Where both `[]` and `""` actually represent the same value: an empty string.

So I wrote a **`TypeAdapter`** like this :

```
public class StringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {

    }

    @Override
    public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        if(in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY){
            return "";
        }
        return in.nextString();
    }
}
```

Then I registred it like this :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(String.class, new StringAdapter()).create();

RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                            .setEndpoint(END_POINT)
                            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                            .build();
```

However, it still yields me the same error when parsing :

> `retrofit.`**`RetrofitError`**: `com.google.gson.`**`JsonSyntaxException`**: `java.lang.`**`IllegalStateException`**: Expected a name but was `BEGIN_ARRAY` at line 1 column 85 path `$.Data.Classified`

I guess I missunderstood something, but what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check for the element with `in.peek()`, but you need to consume the value out of the input stream, or it gets in the way of processing the next element.  You can do that with `in.skipValue`

```
@Override
public String read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
        in.skipValue();
        return "";
    }
    return in.nextString();
}
```